# How to remove an object from a JSON file preserving the file structure

Tags: jq

I have a JSON file with the following structure:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
       "subId": "201805111305QIN0A",
       "checkId": "201805111305QIN0A-CPIFK5ZG"
    },
    {
       "subId": "201805111305QIN0A",
       "checkId": "201805111305QIN0A-F7HGMZUV"
    },
    {
       "subId": "201805111305QIN0A",
       "checkId": "201805111305QIN0A-TQCYEITA"
    },
    {
       "subId": "201805111323U8B1D",
       "checkId": "201805111323U8B1D-HO648V2L"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I would like to do is remove the object where the checkId = "**201805111305QIN0A-TQCYEITA**" and make my file look like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
       "subId": "201805111305QIN0A",
       "checkId": "201805111305QIN0A-CPIFK5ZG"
    },
    {
       "subId": "201805111305QIN0A",
       "checkId": "201805111305QIN0A-F7HGMZUV"
    },
    {
       "subId": "201805111323U8B1D",
       "checkId": "201805111323U8B1D-HO648V2L"
    }
  ]
}
```

To do this I am using the following command line:

```
jq -r '.data[] | del(select (.checkId=="201805111305QIN0A-TQCYEITA")) | select (.!=null)' /var/data-disable.js
```

I was able to delete the desired object, but **the output of the jq command does not preserve the structure of my JSON file**, which looks exactly like this:

```
{
  "subId": "201805111305QIN0A",
  "checkId": "201805111305QIN0A-CPIFK5ZG"
}
{
  "subId": "201805111305QIN0A",
  "checkId": "201805111305QIN0A-F7HGMZUV"
}
{
  "subId": "201805111323U8B1D",
  "checkId": "201805111323U8B1D-HO648V2L"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `del` you could use `map(select(..))`, excluding the part you need.

```
jq '.data |= map(select(.checkId != "201805111305QIN0A-TQCYEITA"))'
```

Or using your actual `del` command, doing the reverse of above

```
jq 'del(.data[] | select(.checkId == "201805111305QIN0A-TQCYEITA"))'
```